# Best way to notify when TIMESTAMP expires?

Tags: mysql, linux

Assume there's some table with a field named "Expires".

User creates a record and Expires is set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP plus some offset in the future (say, 48 hours).

When CURRENT_TIMESTAMP = Expires (i.e. 48 hours have passed), we want to notify the user.

What is the best-practices way of doing this? At the moment all I can think of is writing some backend script which checks for these matching records, maybe in batches of some limit, and run that script on a 1 or 5 minute crontab... but is there a better way?

Comment: A cron-job (background process) is the generic method which usually works well enough. Although it it might make sense to have larger granularity (1hr? 1day?). For real-time expiration a MySQL  (update/insert) notification could be setup coupled with a service with a timeout monitor; the monitor would store the immediate expiration times in memory and use some form of timer queue.

Answer (score 1):

Crontab is a solution:

Each 5 minutes

```
**/5 * * * * ~/notify.sh
```

If I'm using linux, I will definitely do in this way.

Editing crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: Thanks.. I'm thinking of using node.js for the script, any reason specifically to use .sh?

Comment: nothing special man, for my work I use bash, but nodejs is good to (also more easy).